# Div overlapping on each other and z-index is not working

Tags: html, css

I have a small query.
I have a carousel & menu (navbar). When i open the nav drawer, the carousel slider indicator is overlapping on them, I'm trying to put it in the background, but it is not working. I have tried with changing the z-index but it didn't work.

> menu section:

```
<!--Menu drawer section-->
    <section id="menuSec">
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay drawerDiv">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="#">home</a>
                <a href="#">who we are</a>
                <a href="#">our beliefs</a>
                <a href="#">our clients</a>
                <a href="#">why we exists</a>
                <a href="#">what do we do</a>
                <a href="#">case studies with process</a>
                <a href="#">contact us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="spanNav" id="myHeader" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
    </section>
```

> CSS:

```
#myNav {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

> Carousel indicators:

> CSS:

```
.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Please refer below image.

[image]

Comment: Can you try to create a fiddle or pen replicating the problem?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i just want to put indicators behind the menu bar.

Comment: You can put more code? Because the problem is z-index but we need see more about the HTML structure and CSS.

Comment: Try to give `z-index` to `nav` parent like `#menuSec{z-index: 9999}`

Comment: thanx awais it works. you can post it as a answer, i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `#myNav` `z-index: 16;` because `Carousel indicators` deafalut `z-index: 15`

```
#myNav {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: create a fiddle or pen replicating the problem